# Member variables in F#

Tags: f#

```
let eval a b = 
    let r = a + b
    printf "calculate.."
    r
type Foo() =
    member this.Eval = eval 5 10
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let f = Foo()
    let a = f.Eval
    let b = f.Eval
    0
```

This calls eval 2 times instead of one time. It seems this.Eval is a function pointer that calls eval every time I call .Eval.

What I really want to have is a variable.

I solved it by doing this...

```
let eval a b = 
    let r = a + b
    printf "calculate.."
    r
type Foo() =
    let e = eval 5 10
    member this.Eval = e
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let f = Foo()
    let a = f.Eval
    let b = f.Eval
    0
```

Is this the correct way of doing this if I just want to have a member variable instead of method?

Comment: What was wrong with the first method that you solved by the second?. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?. The difference is that the first method is a run-time evaluation while the second is compile-time, because `e` is evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: I just want this.Eval to be a variable that I can assign a value at object construction. 
As you have said, the first method is a run-time evaluation but I only want to evaluate the result (eval 5 10) one time.

Comment: I think the second solution is fine, but i would put the let inside the class

Comment: @MadeOfAir - what do you mean by the second being compile-time? It's just possible that the compiler would inline and optimise `e` but there's certainly no guarantee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is the way .NET properties always work, whether in C# or F#. The body of the property is evaluated each time the property is read.

In addition to your solution, which is correct, I'd add that it calculates the value when `Foo` is constructed. You might only want the value to be calculated when you read the property the first time, and if so you can use [`Lazy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233247.aspx) to do that:

```
let eval a b = 
    let r = a + b
    printf "calculate.."
    r
type Foo() =
    // a lazy computation that will be evaluated the first time .Value is called
    let e = lazy eval 5 10
    member this.Eval = e.Value
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let f = Foo()
    let a = f.Eval
    let b = f.Eval
    0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the more idimatic F# style would be:

```
type Foo() =
    let eval a b = 
        let r = a + b
        printf "calculate.."
        r
    let e = eval 5 10
    member this.Eval = e
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let f = Foo()
    let a = f.Eval
    let b = f.Eval
    0
```

i.e. you put the eval inside the class with a let binding to hide the implementation